# Go: transformed channel

Tags: go, generator, channel

Let's say I have an int channel in Go:

```
theint := make(chan int)
```

I want to wrap this channel in a new channel called incremented

```
incremented := make(chan int)
```

Such that:

```
go func() { theint <- 1 }
    <- incremented // 2
```

appended can be assumed to be the only one that reads from the int.

It will work if a run a goroutine in the background

```
go func() {
   for num := range theint {
      incremented <- num + 1
   }
}
```

However, I prefer to do it without a goroutine since I can't control it in my context.

Is there a simpler way to do it?

One thing that came to mind is python's `yield`:

```
for num in theint:
     yield num + 1
```

Is something like this possible in go?

Comment: what's question here?

Comment: "Is there a simpler way to do it?" No. "Is something like this possible in go?" No. "I prefer to do it without a goroutine since I can't control it in my context." there is no need to control it and if there is a need, you can control it, e.g. via a second channel.

Comment: @Volker good answer. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

#### Generator pattern

What you are trying to implement is generator pattern. To use channels and goroutines for implementation of this pattern is totally common practice.

> However, I prefer to do it without a goroutine since I can't control it in my context.

I believe the problem is deadlock

> fatal error: all goroutines are asleep - deadlock!

To avoid deadlocks and orphaned (not closed) channels use `sync.WaitGroup`. This is an idiomatic way to control goroutines.

#### [Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/vyA016oSe8)

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
)

func incGenerator(n []int) chan int {
    ch := make(chan int)
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    wg.Add(len(n))

    for _, i := range n {
        incremented := i + 1
        go func() {
            wg.Done()
            ch <- incremented
        }()
    }

    go func() {
        wg.Wait()
        close(ch)
    }()

    return ch
}

func main() {
    n := []int{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
    for x := range incGenerator(n) {
        fmt.Println(x)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can also consider is having a select on the int channel and an exit channel - in an infinite for loop. You can choose a variable increment value too. Please see code below:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
    "time"
)

func main() {

    var accum int //accumulator of incremented values
    var wg sync.WaitGroup


    c1 := make(chan int)
    exChan := make(chan bool)

    wg.Add(1)
    go func() {
        time.Sleep(time.Second * 1)
        c1 <- 1
        wg.Done()
    }()
    wg.Add(1)
    go func() {
        time.Sleep(time.Second * 2)
        c1 <- 2
        wg.Done()
    }()
    wg.Add(1)
    go func() {
        time.Sleep(time.Second * 2)
        c1 <- 5
        wg.Done()
    }()
    go func() {
        wg.Wait()
        close(exChan)
    }()

    for {
        var done bool

        select {
        case incBy := <-c1: //Increment by value in channel
            accum += incBy
            fmt.Println("Received value to increment:", incBy, "; Accumulated value is", accum)
        case d := <-exChan:
            done = !(d)
        }
        if done == true {
            break

        }
    }

    fmt.Println("Final accumulated value is", accum)
}
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/HmdRmMCN7U

Exit channel not needed, if we are having non-zero increments always. I like @I159 's approach too!

Anyways, hope this helps.